# How to call an ASP.NET web service from client script in an ASP.NET 2.0 web application?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

So I have an asp.net 2.0 web application and I created a web service to post some data from a web form to a database. I now want to use jQuery/AJAX to post the data to the server but since the application is 2.0 and not 3.5+ I don't have the System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService namespace which seems to be needed (I am posting JSON objects)?

Is there a workaround for this (without upgrading the web application to 3.5)?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I installed http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ca9d90fa-e8c9-42e3-aa19-08e2c027f5d6&displaylang=en and restared VS2010 but can still not use the namespace.

Comment: ~ Is there a reason to not upgrade?

Comment: web host limitations and it's not my call to move it to another host unfortunately

Comment: as you may read on MSDN, `System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService` is a class that is available with the version 3.5 of the .NET framework. You dont need anything else to solve your problem...

Comment: the web host doesn't not support 3.5 at the moment hence the issue. Anyway, I copied the .dll files to the projects bin folder and I can now use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this without 3.5. First, install [Microsoft's AJAX Extensions (aka ASP.NET AJAX 1.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ca9d90fa-e8c9-42e3-aa19-08e2c027f5d6&displaylang=en).

Next, you need to add an `HttpModule` to your web.config (or machine.config; your hosting provider may already have this configured):

```
<httpModules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
</httpModules>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a comprehensive solution for this. (Available under .Net framework 2.0+ and Mono)

> [PokeIn](http://pokein.codeplex.com) gives you an enhanced JSON functionality to makes your server side objects available in client side. Simply, it is a Reverse Ajax library which makes it easy to call JavaScript functions from C#/VB.NET and to call C#/VB.NET functions from JavaScript. It has numerous features like event ordering, resource management, exception handling, marshaling, Ajax upload control, mono compatibility, WCF & .NET Remoting integration and scalable server push.

Answer (score 1):

Use Ajax. And include in your project the JSON.NET free library for [JSON Serialization/Deserialization](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) for the server side code.

For the client side just use [JSON in javascript](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Comment: I am using ajax and json but I can't call the webmethod in my web service from client script without the System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService namespace. http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services "To allow JSON calls to be made you have to apply the ASP.NET AJAX Extension's ScriptService attribute to the Web Service class. "

Comment: Yes that's true. I did not understande your question very well at the beginning. I thought you had problems in serializing/deserializing field. Just read too fast... If you're using webforms I think you shall upgrade to .net 3.5 at the least... As drachenstern wrote in the comment: why you dont want to upgrade?